# Javascript merge object with nested properties

Tags: javascript, object, merge

Lets take a look at the example below:

```
var ref = {
    "fullName": {
        "rules": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 4,
            "maxLength": 64
        },
        "description": "Full name of a user."
    }
};

var user = {
    "fullName": {
        "rules": {
            "required": true,
            "maxLength": 128
        },
        "message": "You have submitted a wrong full name."
    }
};
```

Now what I want is this:

1. Merge objects & properties.
2. Keep the properties of the second object IF they are set already (maxLength)

Below is the result that I expect:

```
var res = {
    "fullName": {
        "rules": {
            "required": true,
            "maxLength": 128
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 4
        },
        "description": "Full name of a user.",
        "message": "You have submitted a wrong full name."
    }
};
```

What I have tried:

```
function mergeNestedObjects(firstObject, secondObject) {
    var finalObject = {};
    
    for (var propertyKey in firstObject) {
        var propertyValue = firstObject[propertyKey];
        
        if (typeof(propertyValue) === "object") {
            finalObject[propertyKey] = mergeNestedObjects(firstObject[propertyKey], secondObject[propertyKey]);
        } else if (secondObject[propertyKey] === undefined) {
            finalObject[propertyKey] = firstObject[propertyKey];
        } else {
            finalObject[propertyKey] = secondObject[propertyKey];
        }
    }
    
    return finalObject;
}
```

The function above merges but somehow doesnt nest the properties.

**UPDATE & ANSWER** got it working, I forgot too itterate through the second object, how dumb. Thanks to @AnthonyGrist

```
function mergeProperties(propertyKey, firstObject, secondObject) {
    var propertyValue = firstObject[propertyKey];

    if (typeof(propertyValue) === "object") {
        return mergeNestedObjects(firstObject[propertyKey], secondObject[propertyKey]);
    } else if (secondObject === undefined || secondObject[propertyKey] === undefined) {
        return firstObject[propertyKey];
    }
    
    return secondObject[propertyKey];
}

function mergeNestedObjects(firstObject, secondObject) {
    var finalObject = {};
    
    // Merge first object and its properties.
    for (var propertyKey in firstObject) {
        finalObject[propertyKey] = mergeProperties(propertyKey, firstObject, secondObject);
    }

    // Merge second object and its properties.
    for (var propertyKey in secondObject) {
        finalObject[propertyKey] = mergeProperties(propertyKey, secondObject, firstObject);
    }
    
    return finalObject;
}
```

Comment: You're only ever iterating over the keys of `firstObject`, so your resulting object is only ever going to have the same keys as the first object passed in. You'll also need to iterate over the keys of `secondObject`, and add those which are missing.

Comment: @onlineracoon: I tried your code, and the properties nest correctly.  The only issue is that some of the properties are missing, as Anthony pointed out.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that worked, how stupid of me lol. Now however I got this: http://pastebin.com/Zma8kLY6 can it be made any shorter, it looks like im doing alot of duplicated code

Comment: @onlineracoon You may answer your own question and mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: I want @AnthonyGrist to answer it, since he gave the answer and he deserves the credits

Comment: @onlineracoon You can, at the very least, remove the `else if (secondObject[propertyKey] === undefined) {` in the second `for` loop; you're iterating over the keys of the second object at that point so you know that it definitely does have that key. I might be tempted to go for something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fLkV5/1/ which uses a ternary operator in place of the `else if` and `else`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function mergeProperties(propertyKey, firstObject, secondObject) {
    var propertyValue = firstObject[propertyKey];

    if (typeof(propertyValue) === "object") {
        return mergeNestedObjects(firstObject[propertyKey], secondObject[propertyKey]);
    } else if (secondObject[propertyKey] === undefined) {
        return firstObject[propertyKey];
    }

    return secondObject[propertyKey];
}

function mergeNestedObjects(firstObject, secondObject) {
    var finalObject = {};

    // Merge first object and its properties.
    for (var propertyKey in firstObject) {
        finalObject[propertyKey] = mergeProperties(propertyKey, firstObject, secondObject);
    }

    // Merge second object and its properties.
    for (var propertyKey in secondObject) {
        finalObject[propertyKey] = mergeProperties(propertyKey, secondObject, firstObject);
    }

    return finalObject;
}
```

Comment: There is a flaw in this. This fails when we merge a = {a: {z: 1}, b: {y:1}, c:{z:1}}; b = {c:{zye: 1}}; Because we are not checking if the key exist in the second object in the call: return mergeNestedObjects(firstObject[propertyKey], secondObject[propertyKey])

Answer (score 2):

Pretty old question, but can be useful. 
A little bit of recursion.

```
function mergeObjects(og, so) {
    for (var key in so) {
        if (typeof (og[key]) === 'object') {
            mergeObjects(og[key], so[key]);
        } else {
            if (og[key] || typeof (og[key]) === 'boolean') {
                og[key] = so[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return og;
}

mergeObjects(ref, user);
```